# ruby regexp to replace equations

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have a some HTML text in mathjax format:

```
text = "an inline \\( f(x) = \frac{a}{b} \\) equation, a display equation \\[ F = m a \\] \n and another inline \\(y = x\\)"
```

(Note: equations are delimited by single slashes, e.g. `\(`, not `\\(`, the extra `\` is just escaping the first one for ruby text).

I want to get the output that substitutes this into, say an image created by latex.codecogs, e.g.

```
desired_output = "an inline <img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?f(x) = \frac{a}{b}\inline"/> equation, a display equation <img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?F = m a"/> \n and another inline <img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?y = x\inline"/> "
```

Using Ruby.  I try:

```
desired = text.gsub("(\\[)(.*?)(\\])", "<img src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\2\" />") 
desired = desired.gsub("(\\()(.*?)(\\))", "<img src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\2\\inline\")
desired
```

But this is unsuccessful, returning only the original input.  What did I miss?  How do I construct this query appropriately?

Comment: In case anyone is looking for it, the Jekyll plugin I've written to replace mathjax equations with images is here: https://github.com/cboettig/labnotebook/blob/32fcfcbc6f8d83b51d33d8d606ee1e51052dc4b0/_plugins/jekyll-labnotebook-plugins/codecogs.rb thanks to @justin-ko for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
desired = text.gsub(/\\\[\s*(.*?)\s*\\\]/, "<img src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\\1\"/>") 
desired = desired.gsub(/\\\(\s*(.*?)\s*\\\)/, "<img src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\\1\inline\"/>")
desired
```

The important changes that had to happen:

- The first parameter for `gsub` should be a regex (as Anthony mentioned)
- If the second parameter is a double-quoted string, then the back references have to be like `\\2` (instead of just `\2`) (see the [rdoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub))
- The first parameter was not escaping the `\`

There were a couple of other minor formatting things (spaces, etc).

Comment: brilliant, thanks for working this one out.  It's amazing how much regexpr can differ between languages. Thanks for a good explanation and a clean reg expression!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your regexp is right - but in Ruby, Regexp are delimited by `//`, try like this :

```
desired = text.gsub(/(\\[)(.*?)(\\])/, "<img src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?\2\" />")
```

You were trying to do string substition, and of course gsub wasn't finding a string containing `(\\[)(.*?)(\\])`