# Conversion of Mathjax in RSS feed to images also converts non-LaTeX strings

Tags: ruby, regex, rss, jekyll, mathjax

I have setup a Jekyll blog with pandoc and the MathJax extension display LaTeX, which works just fine on the site itself. However, as is well known, MathJax does not work in the RSS feed (no Javascript). A common way around that is to use a service like [codecogs.com](http://www.codecogs.com/) that can produce image files from LaTeX-style math just by calling a URL.

I have encountered a problem with [a common codecogs regex-expression used to replace mathjax with images](https://github.com/cboettig/labnotebook/blob/master/_plugins/jekyll-labnotebook-plugins/codecogs.rb) in such RSS feeds. This question could be considered an edge case of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166112/ruby-regexp-to-replace-equations).

Specifically, the MathJax/codecogs/Ruby approach above uses this regex `/\\\[\s*(.*?)\s*\\\]/` which happens to not only match inline LaTeX blocks, but also matches common regular expressions elsewhere, e.g., *inside* R Markdown code chunks. Say we have a code chunk containing this line:

```
sub("\\([.0-9]+\\s[A-Za-z]+\\)", "", somestring)
```

Now, first of all, I did not expect Jekyll/Ruby to try to look for inline LaTeX inside code chunks. What happens then, is that both `\([.0-9]+\` and `\s[A-Za-z]+\` will match the regex (that was meant to replace inline LaTeX code) and be replaced by images showing them as rendered LaTeX, *in the middle of the code chunk*. Not very nice.

I tried to tweak the LaTeX-matching regex to make it more specific, but that quickly exhausted my regex-skills and got me nowhere.

I need some help, what is the best solution to this little problem?

- Somehow making the regex more specific?
- Or is there some Jekyll/Ruby way to exclude all/some code chunks from consideration before even applying the regex (appears like the most elegant choice to me)?
- Or should I look for some completely different way to get around this issue?

Comment: For the third bullet point, are you aware of  [MathJax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node)?

Comment: @peter-krautzberger No, I wasn't. But my site already uses MathJax, via the markdown interpreter (pandoc). Except for the RSS feed, which is why the quick-and-dirty ruby script is used. At least, that's my understanding of the issue. Are you saying I should switch to MathJax-node instead of MathJax? Would that mean I'd have to change markdown interpreter as well?

Comment: No need to change anything. MathJax-node allows you to preprocess content with MathJax using Nodejs, e.g. to generate SVG or even pngs. So you could write a small script that processes your feed xml before publication and adds images generated by MathJax.