# Using plugins in Jekyll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I have been using Jekyll for a month or two now, I am also new to Ruby so learning every day.

In my site I want to add the reading time of blog posts, I have found this ruby gem which will let me do it

https://github.com/garethrees/readingtime

I install it in the normal way into my sites root and add the code needed and nothing happens. This isn't a shock because I have no actually link to it in my sites root?

So it my site looks like this html wise

```
---
layout: default
---

 <div class="twelve columns">
        <h3>{{ page.title }}</h3>
        <span class="date">Wrote by Josh Hornby</span> 
 <span class="date">Estimated reading time – <%= @article.body.reading_time %> </span>
        <br /> <br />
         <%= @article.body %>
        {{ content }}
         </article>

        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check out this blog by @joshua_hornby - www.joshhornby.co.uk"> <div class="twitter_button"> <img src="/images/twitter.png" alt="twitter-logo" width="50" height="50" /> </div> </a> 
  </div>

    <div class="four columns">
        <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
        <p>Find out what else I've been talking about:</p>
           {% for post in site.related_posts limit: 10 %}
        <ul class="square">
            <li><a class="title" style="text-decoration:none;" href="{{post.url}}"><strong>{{ post.title }}</strong></a>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Now I'm not shocked that its not working but my question is how to a install the gem so I can access it in my Jekyll file? Do I need to create a `_plugin` directory and call it from there? Or won't it work as its not a jekyll plugin? In that case I may have a little project writing my own Ruby Jekyll plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have surmised, you cannot call arbitrary ruby commands in your html using `<%`.  Instead, you want to write a plugin which defines a Liquid filter.  In your html above, you would use the liquid tag to grab the content of the page.  You might want to brush up on [liquid-for-designers](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) and [liquid-for-programmers](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers) as well as the [Jekyll notes on writing liquid extensions](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Liquid-Extensions) before we dive in, but I'll try to explain.

First, we need to use a Jekyll filter to grab the content of the page, which we will pass to our plugin for analysis.  Above you have an `@article.body` which probably means something to a ruby on rails site, but doesn't mean anything to Jekyll.  As you see in the center of your layout file, the content for the page is simply called `content`.  It is pulled in through a Liquid output, indicated by the `{{` `}}`.

In place of the line

```
<span class="date">Estimated reading time – <%= @article.body.reading_time %> </span>
```

We want a line that grabs the content and passes it to our plugin:

```
<span class="date">Estimated reading time – {{ content | readingtime }} </span>
```

The vertical bar is a filter, meaning pipe `content` to the function `readingtime` and include the output.  Now we need to write the plugin itself.  In the `_plugins` directory, we create a ruby script following the standard template for a Liquid filter:

```
require 'readingtime'
module TextFilter
  def readingtime(input)
    input.reading_time
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_filter(TextFilter)
```

And save the above as something like `readingtime.rb` in `_plugins`.  It's kinda self explanatory, but you see this tells ruby to load the gem, and define a filter that takes its input and applies the `reading_time` function to that string.

A little note: `content` will pull in the HTML version of the content, not a plain text string.  I don't know if the readingtime gem needs a plain text string, but you can of course convert between them using a little extra ruby code.  If necessary, that's left as an exercise to the reader (though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159286/how-can-i-access-un-rendered-markdown-content-in-jekyll-with-liquid-tags) might help).