# In my Jekyll include file how do I get the markdown for a post?

Tags: jekyll

Is there a way to get ahold of a posts markdown in an include file?

My include file has this code:  `{{workingPost.content}}`

When I include this in a markdown file I get the HTML. I pass that to another include that expects markdown and instead this is passing HTML.

Is there a way to access the markdown instead of the HTML for the post?

As requested here are the code files. What they do is get a featured post for the right hand side of the site like [this](http://www.bitcoinbulls.net/We-Convert-All-Dollars-to-Bitcoin.html). In that link the code is static HTML. I want to update it to make it dynamic via the following code. I already have the first image grabbing code working when it receives markdown. I'd like to use that code to grab the first image from the post here too, but by the time the code gets it the markdown has been turned into HTML.

#### Include file timely.html

```
{% assign workingPost = nil %}
{% for page in site.posts %}
  {% if page.title == 'We Convert All Dollars To Bitcoin' %}
    {% assign workingPost = page %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Popular</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
          <a href="{{workingPost.url}}">
            {% assign workingPostContent = workingPost.content %}
            {% include first-post-image-src2.html param=workingPostContent %}
                <img src="{% include first-post-image-src2.html param=workingPostContent %}" alt="{{workingPost.title}}">
          <p>{{workingPost.excerpt}}</p>
              <p class="btn btn-md btn-success" role="button">READ POST</p>
              <br>
              <br>
          </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

#### include file first-post-image-src2.html

```
{% capture result %}
{% assign htmlAgain= 'empty' %}
{% assign foundImageAgain = 0 %}
      {% assign imagesAgain = include.param | split:"![" %}
      {% for imageAgain in imagesAgain %}
        {% if imageAgain contains '](' %}
          {% if foundImageAgain == 0 %}
            {% assign htmlAgain = imageAgain | split:"](" %}
            {% assign htmlAgain = htmlAgain[1] %}
            {% assign htmlAgain = htmlAgain | split:")" | first %}
            {% assign foundImageAgain = 1 %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
{%endcapture%}{{site.url}}{{htmlAgain|strip}}
```

Comment: Can we see more code. Or maybe a repository ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel thanks for looking into this (as well as my other qs) I added the code since it isn't working and isn't checked into the github repo: https://github.com/davidsilvasmith/bitcoinbulls.net/tree/gh-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes translating from markdown to html is one of the first thinks made when Jekyll build. So, no way to grab the markdown in an include. The only way to bypass this limitation is to do it with a plugin. But it's not the subject.

Now back to you code. It's to complicated and fragile.

Jekyll has all the needed functionalities to do what you want to do. Don't try to do data processing with liquid. Use the tags and filters and you will not have to fear a Gem upgrade that will break your site and bring you to a really difficult debugging.

eg : somewhere in your code, you're processing a string with a `| split:"/>"` filter that rely on how kramdown is rendering `ìmg` tag. If one day they decide to remove this [useless closing slash](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#start-tags), your code will break.

The way you can go : put all the datas in your post, in the simplest form possible, and then use them with simple Jekyll tags and filter.

The idea is to use [yaml Front Matter custom variables](http://jekyllrb.dev/docs/frontmatter/#custom-variables) and Jekyll [post or page excerpt functionalities](http://jekyllrb.dev/docs/posts/#post-excerpts).

In your _config.yml, define a new excerpt separator :

```
excerpt_separator: "<!-- excerpt end -->" # default is "\n\n" = two new lines
```

In **all your posts** :

```
---
excerpt_image_src: "/images/dollarsToBitcoins.jpg"
excerpt_image_alt: "Bitcoin Bulls converts dollars to bitcoins."
popular : true # I'll explain that latter
---
Bitcoin Bulls customers pay in USD but those dollars are all converted to bitcoin.
<!-- excerpt end -->

Bulls, I'm excited to announce...
```

In **default.html**

```
{% if page.is_post %}
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="{{ site.name }} — Atom" href="{{ site.url }}/blog/feed.atom" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{ site.url }}{{ page.excerpt_image_src | strip_newlines }}" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="{{page.excerpt}}" />
    {% else %}
```

In **_includes/timely.html** :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading text-center">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Popular</h3>
  </div>
  {% for p in site.posts %}{% if p.popular == true %}
  <div class="panel-body">
    <a href="{{p.url}}">
            <img src="{{p.excerpt_image_src}}" alt="{{excerpt_image_alt}}">
      <p>{{p.excerpt}}</p>
          <p class="btn btn-md btn-success" role="button">READ POST</p><br><br>
        </a>
  </div>
  {% endif %}{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Note the `{% if p.popular == true %}` that filter posts with a front matter variable `popular: true`.

In **_includes/blog-post.html** :

```
<li>
  <a href="{{ post.url }}">
    <p>{{post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}</p>
    <img src="{{post.excerpt_image_src}}" alt="{{post.excerpt_image_alt}}">

    <!-- No need to wrap excerpt in <p> tag, Jekyll does it.
         If you want to put your own tag :
         <div>{{ post.excerpt | strip_html }}</div> -->
    {{ post.excerpt }}

    <p class="btn btn-md btn-success" role="button">READ POST</p><br><br>
  </a>
</li>
```

In **_layouts/post.html** :

```
<h1>{{page.title}}</h1>
<div style="color:#666;">by David Smith on {{page.date | date: "%B %d, %Y"  }}</div>
{% if page.excerpt_image_src %}
    <p><img src="{{page.excerpt_image_src}}" alt="{{page.excerpt_image_alt}}"></p>
{% endif %}
{{ page.content | remove: page.excerpt | markdownify }}
<br>
```

As you're not actually displaying post excerpt in post page, it's `{{ page.content | remove: page.excerpt | markdownify }}`. If you want to display excerpt it's : `{{ page.content | markdownify }}`

I don't know why but page.content return mardown and not html, so the filter `| markdownify` to transform markdown to html.

Et voila ! Long live Bitcoinbulls !

Comment: Thanks for the epic answer! Great points about the parsing code breaking from changes in the way markdown is rendered. I've thought about putting the image in the Frontmatter. That is the clearest solution, however it bugs me as a writer. Not sure why :)

Comment: I understand you can feel that your post unity is broken by putting one of the image url in the front matter. But this data is still in the document. And this image as a particular role as the post's "logo", so splitting post logo, excerpt and body allows you to combine them as you like when it comes to presentation ("decorating" post with template)

Answer (score 0):

The markdown isn't available. It is rendered earlier and not available.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159286/how-can-i-access-un-rendered-markdown-content-in-jekyll-with-liquid-tags) it sounds like the markdown isn't available.

In my case I made my first-post-image-src2.html include handle the case where it gets markdown or HTML like this:

```
{% capture result %}
{% assign htmlAgain= 'empty' %}
{% assign foundImageAgain = 0 %}
  {% if include.param contains '![' %}
      {% assign imagesAgain = include.param | split:"![" %}
      {% for imageAgain in imagesAgain %}
        {% if imageAgain contains '](' %}
          {% if foundImageAgain == 0 %}
            {% assign htmlAgain = imageAgain | split:"](" %}
            {% assign htmlAgain = htmlAgain[1] %}
            {% assign htmlAgain = htmlAgain | split:")" | first %}
            {% assign foundImageAgain = 1 %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
    {% if foundImageAgain ==0 %}
    {% assign imagesAgain = include.param | split:"<img" %}
      {% for imageAgain in imagesAgain %}
        {% if imageAgain contains 'src="' %}
          {% if foundImageAgain == 0 %}
            {% assign htmlAgain = imageAgain | split:'src="' %}
            {% assign htmlAgain = htmlAgain[1] %}
            {% assign htmlAgain = htmlAgain | split:'"' | first %}
            {% assign foundImageAgain = 1 %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{%endcapture%}{{site.url}}{{htmlAgain|strip}}
```