How can I get all the citation-style links in a markdown page using Liquid?
Markdown supports a citation style of linking, where you place semantic link names at the bottom of the file:
Today I found a [movie][EEAAO] that [changed my life].

[EEAAO]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_Everywhere_All_at_Once
[changed my life]: https://blog.example.com/This-movie-changed-my-life

I want to use Liquid to extract these citation links so I can list sources at the bottom of the page.
Is there any way to do that?

Liquid itself doesn't natively parse markdown, but you can manually extract and process the links
{% assign markdown_content = page.content %}

{%- comment -%}
   Split the markdown content into lines
{%- endcomment -%}
{% assign lines = markdown_content | split: "\n" %}

{%- comment -%}
   Loop through the lines and look for lines matching the citation link format
{%- endcomment -%}
<ul>
{% for line in lines %}
  {%- comment -%}
     Match lines like [key]: URL
  {%- endcomment -%}
  {% if line contains ']: ' %}
    {% assign link_parts = line | split: ']: ' %}
    {% assign link_name = link_parts[0] | remove: "[" %}
    {% assign link_url = link_parts[1] | strip %}

    <li>
      <strong>{{ link_name }}</strong>: <a href="{{ link_url }}">{{ link_url }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>


However, you must ensure that the citation links always appear in the expected format: [name]: URL as liquid doesn’t support full regex functionality like traditional programming languages.

I tried this, but page.content seems to only contain the rendered HTML, which doesn't contain the markdown links

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184659/453435
